# Edit Text remove spans on backspace. Show plain text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am using Edit Text to show tags kind of view. Using SpannableStringBuilder class for setting spans. But, while pressing backspace, spans should be removed to show plain text. How can it be achieved.

Following is the code:

```
hashTags.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (count >= 1 && !isEdit) {
                if (!Character.isSpaceChar(s.charAt(0))) {
                    if (s.charAt(start) == ' ')
                        setTag(); // generate chips
                } else {
                    hashTags.getText().clear();
                    hashTags.setSelection(0);
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (isEdit) {
                setTag();
            }

        }
    });
  public void setTag() {
    if (hashTags.getText().toString().contains(" "))
    {

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(hashTags.getText());
        String chips[] =hashTags.getText().toString().trim().split(" ");
        int x = 0;
        tags.clear();
        for (String c : chips) {
            LayoutInflater lf = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            TextView textView = (TextView) lf.inflate(
                    R.layout.tag_edittext, null);

            tags.add(c);

            /*textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
                    0, android.R.drawable.ic_delete, 0);*/
            textView.setText(c); // set text
            int spec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0,
                    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            textView.measure(spec, spec);
            textView.layout(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                    textView.getMeasuredHeight());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(),
                    textView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
            canvas.translate(-textView.getScrollX(), -textView.getScrollY());
            textView.draw(canvas);
            textView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap cacheBmp = textView.getDrawingCache();
            Bitmap viewBmp = cacheBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            textView.destroyDrawingCache(); // destory drawable
            BitmapDrawable bmpDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(viewBmp);
            int width = bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() ;
            int height = bmpDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() ;

            bmpDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable), x, x + c.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            x = x + c.length() + 1;
        }

        isEdit = false ;
        hashTags.setText(ssb);
        hashTags.setSelection(hashTags.getText().length());
    }

}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? C#? Java? Add it to your tags and mention it in the question.

Comment: Its android. Already mentioned in the question and tags. And more specifically its Java

Answer (score 0):

check this text Wacher code and assign it to your editText.
thanks to "if(after==0)" we can figure out BackSpace Button clicked and by **assigning a new value into the edit text we can simply remove the spans**.

My code in Kotlin:

```
       val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
       override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            if(after==0 && s.length>1){

                    et_sessionTag.setText(et_sessionTag.text.toString().substring(0, s.length - 1))
                    et_sessionTag.setSelection(et_sessionTag.text.length)

            }
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
         //fill if you needed
        }


        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        //fill if you needed
        }
```

Comment: (after == 0) does not tell us that we deleted a character in all cases